# How to use Mailgun (PHP) to forward image attachments?

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm using the [PHP Mailgun SDK](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php) as a middleman for my users, giving them the option of masking their e-mail address. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how attach any inline images. They show up as broken: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTgRo.png

Mailgun has [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples) but it is outdated and does not provide all the information I need.

The documentation says to use the `attachment` parameter for attachments, and this works as expected: the attached images are appended to the end of the e-mail and are downloadable as regular attachments.

It also says to use the `inline` parameter for [inline attachments](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api). For my tests, I'm attaching inline images through my e-mail client (Thunderbird): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGgeh.png

When I use the `inline` parameter, I get the same broken link as in the above image. However, the image is NOT appended to the end of the email as a preview.  I am still able to download it, but this is not the functionality I'm looking for as it is not what the user meant to send.

Furthermore, even if it did work this way, as far as I can tell there is no way to distinguish between the attachments being inline or regular attachments. How would I programmatically detect which parameter to use?

Mailgun posts to my `webhook.php` file which processes the e-mails and sends them. I have the entire `_POST` array to work with, which contains the following pertinent information:

```
_POST Array
(
    ...
    [attachment-count] => 2
    [content-id-map] => {
        "<part1.17612FDA.F9617321@example.com>": "attachment-1",
         "<part2.4AD638E8.B19C97BE@example.com>": "attachment-2"}
    ...
)
```

I also have access to the `_FILES` array, which looks like this in this example:

```
_FILES Array
(
    [attachment-1] => Array
        (
            [name] => google.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpy8JHpc
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 118408
        )

    [attachment-2] => Array
        (
            [name] => logo.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpWcT38i
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 62404
        )

)
```

Here is the code I'm using to create the file array:

```
$files_array = [];
foreach($content_map as $cid => $attachment) {
    $file = $_FILES[$attachment];

    // Create attachment info to add to $files_array
    $arr = [];
    $arr["filePath"] = $file["tmp_name"];
    $arr["filename"] = $file["name"];
    $files_array[] = $arr;
}

// Resulting format example:
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [filePath] => /tmp/phpy8JHpc
        [filename] => google.png
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [filePath] => /tmp/phpWcT38i
        [filename] => logo.png )
    )
)
```

And the code to actually send it:

```
$this->mailgun->messages()->send($domain, [
  'from'          => $email_from, 
  'to'            => $email_to, 
  'subject'       => $subject, 
  'html'          => $message, 
  'h:Return-Path' => $email_from,
  'h:Reply-To'    => $email_from,
  // AND EITHER OF THE FOLLOWING:
  'attachment'    => $files_array,
  'inline'        => $files_array,
]);
```

Here is what the image looks like when I view source (after formatting for readability):

```
<img
    moz-do-not-send="false"
    src="cid:part1.17612FDA.F9617321@example.com"
    alt="fdsa"
    width="380"
    height="160">
```

What I've tried:

- Attaching the images regularly, using both `inline` and `attachments` parameters then sending the e-mail, hoping Mailgun figures out the rest
- Attaching the images using both parameters, and replacing "cid:part1..." with "cid:/tmp/phpy8JHpc"
- Attaching the images using both parameters, and replacing "cid:part1..." with "cid:google.png"
- Attaching the images using both parameters, and replacing "cid:part1..." with "cid:/tmp/phpy8JHpc/google.png"

As stated before, the e-mails send fine. The images get attached, but not the way I want them to. I get no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I went thru a very similar issue in this week.

I managed to fix it by first identifying which files are (actually) in-line images and which are not. I’ve used a regular expression to find in the message body the tags (eg. cid:1234) based on the content-id-map.

These (inline images) I’ve appended to the “inline” property to be sent to Mailgun. All the other files that CID are not found in the message body, I’ve appended to the “attachment” property.

The tricky part (at least for me) was to figure out that it would only work when the files appended to “inline” should not use their (actual) names (eg my-file.jpg) as the “filename”, but use their CID instead.

Note that the filename should be given without the “<“ and “>”!

I hope this can help you!